# Upgrade runtime parachain when relay is local

Tags: upgrade

I know that to upgrade a runtime of a parachain, we need to go to parachainSystem.

But when we use a local relay chain, how could we access to the polkadot-js of the parachain ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the `${RPC_ENDPOINT}` with yours.

```
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=${RPC_ENDPOINT}#/explorer
```

Tips:

Make sure you have set up your parachain ws endpoint correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I launched my parachain with "./target/release/parachain-template-node \ --alice \ --collator \ --force-authoring \ --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \ --base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \ --port 40333 \ --ws-port 8844 \ -- \ --execution wasm \ --chain ../polkadot/raw-local-chainspec.json \ --port 30343 \ --ws-port 9977". 

I then tried to connect as you said with : https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8844#/explorer but it tells me "waiting to establish a connexion".

Comment: You don't have a domain name and certificate. So, you can't use https/wss. And you should also set allow insecure content in your browser setting for polkadot.js.org. Since you are trying to connect to ws through https. polkadot.js.org is https, and your node is ws.

Comment: Basically, I putted my local node, but I have a domain and certificate with nginx : it is testparachainkusama.fr.

Comment: My relay and parachain are running, but I don't manage to connect to my parachain with 8844 port ! Am I clear ?

Comment: Nope. From the URL that you gave me. Apparently, you are using wss://127.0.0.1 instead of a domain name. It's totally wrong. Use ws + ip or wss + domain name.

Comment: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Ftestparachainkusama.fr%3A443#/explorer

Here is my node ! I have a domain ! I just don't manage to connect to my parachain ! (I want to make a parachain upgrade) ! When I do https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Ftestparachainkusama.fr%3A8844#/explorer it does not work !

Comment: Add `--rpc-cors all --unsafe-ws-external` to your boot flags. This should be only used on full node or dev env.

Comment: Ok, so I stop my parachain, I ask for a new paraID, I run it with the same comment and add your two arguments ; then I will be able to see it on wss://testparachainkusama.fr:8844. Right ? If yes, thanks for your help AurevoirXavier

Comment: I'm not sure if wss work with port. I recommend using ws://127.0.0.1:8844.

Comment: I have the certificate with my domain testparachainkusama.fr. 

I will try wss://testparachainkusama.fr:8844, and if does not work, i will put ws://testparachainkusama.fr:8844 !

Comment: If I don't use wss, it tells me I can't connect with ws to a https. But with wss://testparachainkusama.fr:8844 it is still looking for a connexion. Any ideas ?